# How to instantiate an object witn an enum parameter in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, oop

I am trying to instantiate an object 'Bug bug' with 3 parameters and one of them is enumerator. Here is my class:

```
 class Bug 
{
private:
    int Id;
    string description;
    enum severity { low, medium, severe} s;

public:
    Bug(void);
     Bug(int id, string descr, severity x)
              :Id(id), description(descr), s(x)
     {}

    void printDetails()
    {
       cout<< "Severity level:" <<s<< " Description: " <<description<<" ID= " 
       <<Id<< endl;
    }
   ~Bug(void);
```

};

this is my main.cpp:

```
    #include "Bug.h"
    int main(){

    Bug bg(3,"a", low);//Error message: identifier "low" is undefined

     return 0;
    }
```

when I added this line to the main

```
    enum severity { low, medium, severe};
```

the error message has changed to this:

```
      Bug bg(3,"a", low);//Error message: no instance of constructor "Bug::bug" matches the argument list
```

Any ideas how to do this right?

Comment: Try `Bug::low`, or `Bug::severity::low`.

Comment: Move the enum definition to public section. main() cannot see it , because it is privet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes as follows, see *my comments*

---

```
class Bug 
{


public:
    // If you intent to use severity outside class , better make it public
    enum severity { low, medium, severe} ;

    Bug(void);
     Bug(int id, string descr, severity x)
              :Id(id), description(descr), s(x)
     {}

    void printDetails()
    {
       cout<< "Severity level:" <<s<< " Description: " <<description<<" ID= " 
       <<Id<< endl;
    }

   ~Bug()
   {
       // Fix your constructor, they don't have void parameter and must have a body
   }

   // Moving private section, just to use the severity declaration in public section
private:
    int Id;
    string description;
    severity s ;    // use an instance of severity for internal use
};

int main()
{
    Bug bg(3,"a", Bug::low); // now use severity values using Bug::


}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your enum exists inside the `Bug` class, whereas your main function is outside the class. This is how it has to be.

So the correct way to reference the enum from your main function would be:

`Bug bg(3,"a", Bug::low);`

However, you need to define the enum inside the `public` section of the class. It's currently inside the `private` section, which will prevent the main function from being able to access it.

Note that you will also need to define the enum as a type within the class separate from the private member variable that uses it. So your class defininition should become something like this:

```
class Bug 
{
public:
    typedef enum {low, medium, severe} severity;
    Bug(void);
     Bug(int id, string descr, severity x)
              :Id(id), description(descr), s(x)
     {}

    void printDetails()
    {
       cout<< "Severity level:" <<s<< " Description: " <<description<<" ID= " 
       <<Id<< endl;
    }
   ~Bug(void);

private:
    int Id;
    string description;
    severity s;
};
```

Note that the `public` section needs to be above the `private` section in this class, so that enum type severity is defined before it's used.

Answer (score 0):

Move enum to public area and try to use:

```
Bug bg(3,"a", Bug::severity::low);
```

Comment: you need to move it from private section to public

Comment: I moved enum severity to public and used this in main:                     
      Bug bg(3,"a", Bug::low);
It worked, thanks!

Comment: that enum is private, plus, is not a class, it doesn't retain the name "severity", that namespace do not exist.

Comment: @Art there are other problems with your code. See my answer.